# Dojo 1.4: Reset dijit.form.FilteringSelect value to previous value onChange

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

http://jsfiddle.net/FYtJH/1

The filtering select needs to warn users that they're about to change the select and if they cancel, reset the value to the previous one.

1. Am I connecting to the right events?
2. The OnBlur event retriggers the change event. If the widget is still focused when I reset the value and you click anywhere outside the widget, it triggers the onchange event again. I'd like to prevent that. Is there a way to set the value but prevent the onChange from firing when blurring the input?

TLDR: Reset filteringSelect to old value and unfocus the widget using confirm dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd missed the obvious fix - I was saving the old value in a local variable - if I'd compared it against the incoming value and halted the onChange functionality right there, it'd fix the onBlur problem.